# CSV remove duplicates and save result in other file whith php

Tags: php, csv, duplicates

I have a CSV file who containe product for my web site.
I want to remove duplicate line in this file and save result in other file,
for exemple in my CSV file I have "ID","GTIN","REF","NAME", .....
I want to analyse the field which corresponds to the name field

I try with this code :

```
<?php
$fic = fopen("st.csv", "a+");
$fic2 = fopen("test.csv", "a+");
$i = 0;
/* 
$products[
    [
        "NAME" => ...,
        "height" => ...,
        "couleur" => ...,
    ]
]
*/
$products= [
    "ID" => [],"GTIN"=> [],"REF"=> [],"NAME"=> [],"HEIGHT"=> [],"COLOR"=> [],"FAMILLY"=> []
];
var_dump($products);
while (($data = fgetcsv($fic)) !== FALSE) {
    var_dump($data);
    foreach ($data as $datas){
        $products["NAME"][$i] = $datas[2][3];
var_dump($products["NAME"]);
        $i++;
    }
}
```